# Data structure which can be sorted with iterator maintaining insertion order

Tags: java

This is a very generalized question, I'll try to be as clear as I can. let's say I have some collection of objects, for simplicity, make them integers. Now I want to make a class which represents these integers as some data structure. In this class I want to implement

- a sort function, which sorts the collection according to some defined sorting logic
- the iterable interface, where the Iterator traverses in insertion order

How could I make it so that, even if I add integers in unsorted order, e.g.

```
someCollection.add(1);
someCollection.add(3);
someCollection.add(2);
```

and then call

```
Collections.sort(someSortingLogic);
```

The iterator still traverses in insertion order, after the collection is sorted. Is there a particular data structure I could use for this purpose, or would it be a case of manually tracking which elements are inserted in which order, or something else I can't think of?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the significance of sorting if iteration order is based on insertion? EDIT: I guess it's an indexable List, since other collections can't be sorted anyway. Please clarify either way.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the ambiguity! I'm not entirely sure myself, I'm required to do this for a small part of my assignment

Comment: Can't the sort method return a copy? That way the original order would be retained.

Comment: This would violate the iterator contract. If a collection has an established order (insertion, natural or explicit), then the iterator must reflect that order. Everything else would be counter-intuitive and thus error prone.

Comment: Why only one datastructure? Seems pretty obvious to me that you need two different collections

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd That's true for a List, not necessarily for other collections.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. I feel like in trying to avoid a definite answer to an assignment question I was being a bit too vague. To provide some context, the actual class in question models a hand of playing cards (e.g. poker). The assignment states that the hand must have sort functions (with my own defined sorting logic) and that also it must implement iterable, where the iterator traverses the cards in the order they were added. It seems like the sort functions should modify the hand itself, not create a copy, which seems strange to me

Comment: @shmosel it's true for any Collection that has an order of any kind, e.g. also LinkedHashSet and TreeSet.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd What about PriorityQueue?

Comment: @shmosel good catch. the Iterator in a PriorityQueue at least *tries* to reflect the order, though it can only approximate it, see this sample: https://ideone.com/iJJmHX . Still, I would call this the exception to the rule, and [the docs explicitly mention the iterator being unordered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator--)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd What rule? The Collection interface doesn't define any concept of ordering outside the iterator itself, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I know, I also didn’t find an explicit rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to solve a problem like this, you maintain two indexes to the values.  Perhaps one of those indexes contains the actual values, perhaps both indexes contain the actual values, or perhaps the actual values are stored elsewhere.

Then when you want to walk the sorted order, you use the sorted index to the values, and when you want the insertion order, you use the insert index to the values.

An index can be as simple as an array containing the values.  Naturally, you can't store two different values into one spot in an array, so a simple solution is to wrap two arrays in an Object, such that calling the Object's `sort()` method sorts one array, while leaving the insertion order array untouched.

Fancier data structures leverage fancier techniques, but they all basically boil down to maintaining two orders, the insertion order AND the sort order.

```
public class SomeCollection {
   public void add(int value) {
      insertArray = expandIfNeeded(insertArray);
      insertArray[insertIndex++] = value;
      sortArray = expandIfNeeded(sortArray);
      sortArray[sortIndex++] = value;
      sort(sortArray);
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you've shown us enough code to give you a good answer, but if you have a class that looks a bit like this:

```
public class Hand implements Iterator<Card>
{
    private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    // Returns iterator for natural ordering of cards
    @Override
    public Iterator<Card> iterator()
    {
        return cards.iterator();
    }

    // Rest of code omitted
```

Then you can implement a `sortedIterator(...)` method like this:

```
    // Returns iterator for sorted ordering by Comparator c
    public Iterator<Card> sortedIterator(Comparator<? super Card> c)
    {
        return cards.stream().sorted(c).iterator();
    }
```

If you show us some more code for what you have written, there may be better solutions.